# How to get the proper PID of a newly created Firefox window in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, firefox, process

Here is a very simple example of the problem I am experiencing:

```
$process = Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' -argumentlist "-new-window https://google.com -foreground" -PassThru

Write-Host $process.Id
```

The firefox window will start and work as expected, it will return a process id, but when I actually check the running processes, I see no results for that PID.

I tried adding this just to see,

```
while (-not $process.HasExited){
    Write-Host "..."
}

Write-Host $process.HasExited
```

And it looks like the process *does* run for maybe a couple milliseconds before it exits.

I'm thinking this may have something to do with how Firefox handles it's own processes. Because I tested a similar setup with some other random apps and they all worked as expected.

Any ideas on how to work around this when it comes to Firefox?

Comment: All modern browsers start more than one process when they start ... even for just one browser window with only one tab in it. What problem do you actually want to solve with your question?

Comment: I want to start a new Firefox window, and know exactly when that specific instance of Firefox is closed. Even if I have other windows/tabs open, I want to be able to keep track of the one specifically created with `Start-Process`. I'm open to hearing other approaches if there is another way to handle this.

Comment: Depending on the actual task you want to accomplish you might loop for firefox processes and their `MainWindowTitle`. This way you'll get at least the currently active tab of last active firefox window.

Answer (score 3):

There are several challenges to overcome:

- The `firefox` process that ends up presenting the actual browser window is different from the one that is *initially launched*. That is, as you've observed, the launched process spawns other processes and *itself* exits quickly.
- As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) points out, modern browsers typically launch *multiple* non-transient processes, so the challenge is how to identify the one that represent the browser window.
- Browsers may *reuse* existing processes, so a single process can present multiple windows / tabs, and closing one of them won't terminate the process as a whole.

  - If you need to ensure that a dedicated, new process is used, you have two options:

    - (a) Make sure that no preexisting Firefox instance is running, either by erroring out, or - if acceptable for your use case - by forcefully terminating all existing instances first (`Stop-Process -Name firefox`).
    - (b) With significantly more effort, create a dedicated, temporary Firefox *profile* that you can launch with the `-new-instance` option, which allows multiple independent Firefox instances to run concurrently and whose lifetime can be tracked separately.

The following - cumbersome - solution implements option (b):

- If no `firefox` process is found, there is no concern about creating independent instances, and Firefox can be launched normally.
- Otherwise, a temporary profile is created, and launched via the `-new-instance` and `-profile` [options](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions) to ensure that a *new* process will be used to present the new browser window.
- After launching the initial process, loop until a `firefox` process appears that was launched *later* and has a *nonempty window title*, which is then presumed to be the real process of interest.
- You can then wait for the termination of this process to know when the dedicated browser window has been closed. If a temporary profile had to be created, it is cleaned up afterwards.

```
# Comment this statement out to silence the verbose messages below.
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$now = Get-Date
$url = 'https://example.org'  # URL to open.

# Launch a (new) Firefox instance.
if ($alreadyRunning = [bool] (Get-Process -ErrorAction Ignore firefox)) {
  # Determine the path for a temporary profile with a unique name.
  $tempProfilePath = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([datetime]::utcnow.tostring('o') -replace '\D')
  Write-Verbose  "Firefox is already running. Creating temp. profile $tempProfilePath..."
  # Note: Creating an empty directory for the profile is seemingly enough.
  $null = New-Item -Type Directory $tempProfilePath
  Write-Verbose "and starting a new instance with it..."
  Start-Process firefox "-new-instance -profile $tempProfilePath $url"
} else {
  Write-Verbose 'Firefox isn''t running. Starting normally...'
  Start-Process firefox $url
}

# Find the newly launched process that is the actual browser window.
Write-Verbose 'Waiting for a recently launched Firefox process with a nonempty window title to appear...'
while (-not (
  $ps = Get-Process firefox | 
    Where-Object StartTime -gt $now |
      Where-Object MainWindowTitle
)) {
  Write-Host -NoNewLine . 
  Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 500 
}
Write-Host

Write-Verbose "Found. Waiting for process to exit..."
$ps.WaitForExit()

Write-Verbose 'Process has exited.'

if ($alreadyRunning) {
  Write-Verbose "Cleaning up temporary profile $tempProfilePath..."
  do {
    # The profile dir. is typically held on to for a little while longer by associated processes that may not have terminated yet.
    Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 200
    Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -Literalpath $tempProfilePath -Recurse -Force
  }
  while (Test-Path -LiteralPath $tempProfilePath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mklement0 work, in your case you can use the parent Process ID.

I use WMI to get the parent process, but it works for the very first launch.

```
$parentProcess = Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' -argumentlist "-new-window https://google.com -foreground" -PassThru
$childProcess = get-process -id $(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'firefox.exe'"  | where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq $parentProcess.id}).ProcessId
# effectively stop the child
$childProcess | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Interesting; I think it's what your answer is trying to say, but just to spell out the limitation explicitly: This won't work if Firefox is _already running_. Aside from that, I would have expected a potential race condition with the `Get-CimInstance` call - the real process may not yet exist by the time the call is made. In practice it seems to work, but I'm not sure it always will. Another thing to consider - although it is a largely hypothetical concern - is the fact that the actual browser window is a (direct) child process of the launching process is somewhat of an implementation detail.